# What happens when a Contractor fails to pay their remuneration?

Tags: darker-than-black

What happens when a Contractor fails to pay their remuneration? Do they lose their ability or what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Although this payment can be delayed, especially in the midst of
>   combat, it is ultimately unavoidable. It is unknown what happens to a
>   Contractor that fails to pay his obeisance, although Amagiri has
>   stated that Contractors who fail to do so seemingly 'melt like butter'
>   when depriving a captured November 11 of his remuneration.

Taken from: http://darkerthanblack.wikia.com/wiki/Obeisance

(It was also a pretty easy google search)